# DOM tree creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

In order to write XML, HTML or any other tree-like structures I once made a small DOM-like, python library with two main functions defined as such :

- `grow(parent_instance, child_tag)` which returns the newly created and appended `child_instance`
- `attach(parent_instance, text)` which append the text and returns the `parent_instance`

Writing trees became a breeze.

Newbie in javascript, (finding `$('<div></div>')` ugly) I tried to implement this again, on top of DOM, and jquery... Am I re-inventing the wheel ? How could it be more javascriptic ?

```
function grow(parent, tagName) {
    var node = $(document.createElement(tagName));
    parent.append(node);
    return node;
}
```

---

**edit @AmmarCSE :**

yuck >_< I start to understand why I still got an error with `.appendChild()` in your first example... `grow()` is called first with a jQuery selected parent (which use `.append()`) and return a classic DOM object, (which use `.appendChild()`).

I have to find a way to keep nestability :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not about re-inventing the wheel or being more 'javascriptic'. You simply have many options to achieve the same goal.

Javascript:

```
function grow(parent, tagName) {
    var node = document.createElement(tagName);
    //notice, the jQuery wrapper was removed as it is not needed

    parent.appendChild(node);
    return node;
}

function attach(parent_instance, text) {
    parent_instance.innerHTML = text;
    return parent_instance;
}
```

jQuery:

```
function grow(parent, tagName) {
    return $(parent).append($(document.createElement(tagName)));
}

function attach(parent_instance, text) {
    return $(parent_instance).text(text);
}
```

Comment: well I'm too much into the "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
" :). When I removed the `$(` in my example I got `TypeError: parent.append is not a function search:42`, with parent obtained via a `$('#id')` selector...

Comment: @yota, I dont understand. Are you experiencing a TypeError with the code above?

Comment: @yota, I accidently got mixed with append for jQuery and appendChild for javascript. I updated my answer.

Comment: @yota, I agree, mixing javascript and jquery can be hideous sometimes. However, the pure javascript version should work now.

Comment: I'm picky but the jQuery-based grow() does not return the child but the parent :)

Answer (score 0):

I found my perfect answer, so I share it.

```
$.fn.grow = function (name) {
    var child = $(document.createElement(name));
    this.append(child);
    return child;
};
```

It adds a jQuery method and enable this kind of procedural tree building:

```
var ord_list = ["first", "second", "third"];
var n_table = $('#ordinals')
for (var i=0 ; i < ord_list.length ; i++) {
    n_tr = n_table.grow('tr');
    n_td = n_tr.grow('td');
    n_td.text(i);
    n_td = n_tr.grow('td');
    n_td.text(ord_list[i]);
}
```

which produces:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>first</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>second</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>third</td></tr>
</table>
```

clean, unobtrusive, I will propose it to jQuery devs :D

.attach() is useless since .text() already exists (thx @AmmarCSE)